# image markers on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, animation, mapkit

Need to use own imaged markers instead built-in pins. I have several questions.
1. Is it legally? I have a doubt because there is no standard support for markers(pins) with own icon.

2. How to make a marker with own icon right way?
   I found the post which actually describe how-to: http://www.arlingtondev.com/thoughts/?p=81. I am a newbie, but it looks like a "crutch", which i do not want to use in my clean code. Could you advise better way? I had a lot of problems while integrate that method and currenlty cannot move and animate icons, that's why decided to ask stackoverflowers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Check the `MKAnnotationView` class, it's specifically designed for that. In fact, `MKPinAnnotationView` inherits from it. Use the `image` field to specify an image.

Comment: If you want to change the latitude/longitude of the marker, change the coordinate of the related `MKAnnotation`. If you want to offset the image, use the `ceterOffset` field of `MKAnnotationView`.
The class reference for `MKMapView` explains the relationship between annotations and annotation views.

Comment: Yeah it helped. Do you know how to update a marker's location without remove-add this marker to mapview, because it updates its real location only after map moves or zoomed.

Comment: I think the only way to update an annotation is to remove it and add it again.