# changing image of current location in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

Is there any way of changing the pin(indicating the current location) for a custom image in a MKMapView in the iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this post helps: [image markers on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033924/image-markers-on-mkmapview)

**Edit**

Also, try [Custom pin animation - MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655465/custom-pin-animation-mkmapview). Looks like he loops through subviews, some or all of which are pin views.